# Excel VBA code to copy active cell in specific column to fixed defined cell

Tags: excel, vba

I've been looking for a way to code in VBA:
when I click on a certain cell (doesn't matter which one, as long it's in column X), Excel should copy that cell value to a specific cell B10.

Can anyone help please?
Probably simple, but I get errors every time!

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code which you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event for that worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 19 Then ' check if cell modifed is in column "S"
    Target.Copy Range("B10")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: should it be `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event ?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick response! Works great, however I need to double click to update the cell. Is there a way to just select it, not double click it?

Comment: yes yes! indeed SelectionChange does the trick! THANKS!! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: @avb thanks :) , it's semi-automatic for me to use the `Change` event and not the `SelectionChange`

Comment: the code works perfectly, but now I noticed it only copies it when it's an actual value. when the content it needs to copy, is a formula, it copies the formula instead of the value.